# How can the macOS calendar show (1 more...) daily events in the month view?

Tags: macos, calendar

When there are too many events on one day, the macOS calendar does not show all events. I know that **resizing the window helps** but the problem is still the same for more daily events. I was expecting that there is a popup window, as in the year view, when I click on "2 more...". However, nothing happens.

**Is there an easy way to see all events?**

(Another workaround may be to use a different calendar app)

[image: macOS calendar month view, too many daily events]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I found is to **double click** "2 more..." or the date number (green rectangles in the picture below). This directly opens the day view of this particular day.

[image: macOS calendar month view click areas]

Answer (score 4):

Two ways I can think of, if you don't want to (or can't) expand the window further…

Swap to Day or Week view - views are  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>  though  <kbd>4</kbd>

Shrink the font -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>  ( <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>+</kbd>  to enlarge)

Comment: Thank you, shrinking the font size also helps! Switching to the day or week view does not always work since the calendar remembers the last day view.

Comment: It remembers the day you last clicked, for sure, even though it gives no indication of that unless you click an event.

Comment: I see. One can click on a particular day (anywhere in "day rectangle") and then switch to the preferred view via the keyboard shortcut. This is particularly useful if one wants to use "week view" (see also my answer which is for "day view").